# What is the name of this statistical measurement?

Tags: statistics, terminology, standard-deviation

We have a target value for $ x $ called $ x_t $, and we have the average value for $ x $ given as $ \overline x $. If we take the absolute value of the average minus the target we get a measure of how far on average we were from the target. What is this measurement called?

Expressed as a formula:

$ y = \left| \overline x - x_t \right|  $

Comment: I would probably call this the average absolute error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known as an [absolute deviation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deviation_(statistics)). They appear in different areas in statistics, most notably being the sample variance $s^2$ and sample standard deviation $s$